# PHP send automatic sysdate and sysdate+24hours

Tags: php

I am passing through variables to a curl call and i need to pass through system date(YMD HMS format) of when someone signs up and then an expiry date of 24 hours later:

```
$post2 = [
    "subscription[name]" => 'magazine one day subscription',
    "subscription[product_id]" => '51',
    "subscription[start_date]" => "date('Y-m-d H:i:s')",
    "subscription[end_date]" =>  "date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+24 hours', time()))",
    "subscription[allowed_no_of_articles]" => '56',

];

$username = "Incisive";
$password = "!atseg9$";



$ch2 = curl_init("http://xxxx.auth.xxx.net/subscriber_individuals/$xml->id/subscriptions.xml");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post2);

$complete = curl_exec($ch2);

curl_close($ch2);

echo $complete;
```

I have tried the date function and this does not work, so i wondered if anyone else has a solution to try any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Erm, you are sending string with a name of a function (date). Why? You should INVOKE the function and save to $post2 array its results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You quoted the `date` function. You may replace:

```
$post2 = [
    "subscription[name]" => 'magazine one day subscription',
    "subscription[product_id]" => '51',
    "subscription[start_date]" => "date('Y-m-d H:i:s')",
    "subscription[end_date]" =>  "date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+24 hours', time()))",
    "subscription[allowed_no_of_articles]" => '56',
];
```

With this:

```
$post2 = [
    "subscription[name]" => 'magazine one day subscription',
    "subscription[product_id]" => '51',
    "subscription[start_date]" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    "subscription[end_date]" =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+24 hours', time())),
    "subscription[allowed_no_of_articles]" => '56',
];
```

Comment: thanks works perfect, for some silly reason did not think of removing quote marks!